# URL anchor is attached to the title attribute in Internet Explorer — why?

Tags: html, internet-explorer, dom, anchor

I found a weird bug that only occurs in Internet Explorer (6 through 9).

Take for example the URL `http://www.spiegel.de/#any_anchor_value` which I open in any Internet Explorer. (From what I can tell it works with any URL)

As soon as the page finishes loading, that anchor tag is attached to the title of the browser window. (In this case even twice…)

[image: IE title bar]

When I inspect the DOM of this page, it even appears in the title tag:

[image: IE DOM]

This works on any website and in any version of the Internet Explorer from 6 through 9.

I can't seem to find much information on this nor have I ever heard of it or even noticed it.

What's the reason for this? What am I missing?

Comment: I can't seem to be able to replicate this on any other site than on `spiegel.de`. Please share more sites where this happens

Comment: Humm… good point. I have a client's website where it happens. But a number of other sites did not show this problem. One more example I found was www.skype.com. Not sure what triggers this behavior…

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is actually the adobe flash embed on the page that is causing the problem.  You get an additional anchor for each instance of flash embedded on the page.

Adobe bug report:
http://bugs.adobe.com/jira/browse/FP-240

Other references:
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/iewebdevelopment/thread/c91e3dc4-ef05-47f9-b799-db149e3ddc80/

Answer (score 0):

it seems because the required id(e.g. any_anchor_value) is not found in the page.

Comment: That might be a part of the explanation, but why doesn't it happen on every website? (See Niklas` comment to my initial post)