# IE embed anchor name # to the Title

Tags: internet-explorer, embed, anchor, title

## The Problem

IE 8 embeds anchor name to the title. In the image below we can see it embeds the #home anchor

It doesn't happens to Chrome or Firefox

[image: Bug Image]

Comment: Thank Adobe. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6436142/url-anchor-is-attached-to-the-title-attribute-in-internet-explorer-why Last time I had this problem, updating the title through JavaScript several times after the Flash was inserted into the page solved it.

Answer (score 0):

Yay, adding

```
<script type="text/javascript">
// <![CDATA[
 window.onload = function()
 {
  document.title = "My Website Title";
 }
// ]]>
</script>
```

To the bottom of the page - just before `</body>` did it!